# An isoperimetric inequality for "order" polytopes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, integration, isoperimetric-problems

I am looking for an isoperimetric inequality for order-like polytopes. 
An order polytope $K\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by a set of linear inequaities: 
$$ \forall i  \; 0\leq x_i \leq 1 $$
and 
$ x_i \leq x_j $
for some of the coordinates. If the constraints define a total order over the coordinates, the polytope $K$ is called a total order polytope.

As in a 
[related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79378/about-the-surface-area-vs-volume-of-polytopes), given a parameter $k$, I am interested in how large can the ratio between the number of boxes which intersect the perimeter of $K$  and the number of boxes contained inside the polytope.

One thought is to think of this as an isoperimetric inequality - if we would expand the polytope by a constant factor, and we knew how much the volume would change - I think that it might help us get that ratio.

Thanks!